# C Code exits with non-zero status

Tags: c

I'm making a program in C that is supposed to ask for two numbers and find their LCM and GCF. However, after asking for those two numbers the code just exits with a non-zero status. [Link to code here](https://repl.it/NKgR/9), any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    //Declare things
    int i;
    int num1,num2 = 0;
    int foundLCM = 0;
    int foundGCF = 0;
    //Ask for input
    printf("\nEnter a positive integer: ");
    scanf("%i", &num1);

    printf("\nEnter another positive integer: ");
    scanf("%i", &num2);
    //Set i to the bigger number
    if(num1 >= num2)
    {
        int i = num1;
    }
    else
    {
        int i = num2;
    }

    //find the GCF
    while(foundGCF == 0)
    {
        if(num1%i == 0 && num2%i == 0)
        {
            printf("\nGreatest Common Factor: %i\n", i);
            foundGCF = 1;
        }

        i--;
    }

    //Find the LCM
    while(foundLCM == 0)
    {
        if(i%num1 == 0 && i%num2 == 0)
        {
            printf("Lowest Common Multiple: %i", i);
            foundLCM = 1;
        } 

        i++;
    }

    //Kill
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post the code here please

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the redeclarations of `i` on lines 21 and 27 and simply assign the value of `i` to `num1` and `num2` respectively. As it stands, `i` is not initialized when it is used in increment/decrement, which results in the program crashing.

Also, you'd need to restore `i` to its initial value after the GCF loop and before the LCM loop. Otherwise, it'll give wrong value in cases where there's no common factor. I'd suggest storing the initial value in some other variable.

See https://repl.it/NKgR/12

Please note that this is not the optimal way to calculate GCF and LCM. You can have a look at Euclid algorithm and implementations for more info.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `i` is not initialized.

```
t.c: In function 'main':
t.c:21:7: warning: unused variable 'i' [-Wunused-variable]
int i = num1;
    ^
t.c:27:7: warning: unused variable 'i' [-Wunused-variable]
int i = num2;
    ^
t.c:37:7: warning: 'i' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
    printf("\nGreatest Common Factor: %i\n", i);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

You should replace `int i = num1;` by `i = num1;`  Same thing for `int i = num2;`